# Issues with Toshiba FlashAir Stand Alone Mode

Tags: flashair

My scenario is the following - have the Toshiba Flash Air connected to a camera, and configured to stand alone mode so that the camera detects a network, a user is able to pull files from Flash Air without switching to the flash air SSID. However, after much pain and dabbling with the configuration file, I am still unable to access the Flash Air url - http://flashair/ through my regular network. Any one managed to configure the card successfully?

My configuration file details:

```
    [Vendor]

APPNAME=myflashair
CIPATH= /DCIM/100__TSB/FA000001.JPG
VERSION=FA9CAW3AW3.00.01
CID=02544d535733324740e3455f79010b01
PRODUCT=FlashAir
VENDOR=TOSHIBA
MASTERCODE=XXXXXXX
APPSSID=flashair
APPNETWORKKEY=XXXXXXXX
LOCK=1
WEBDAV=1
TIMEZONE=32
APPMODE=5
APPAUTOTIME=300000
```

Answer (score 1):

In Station Mode ( `APPMODE=5` ) you have to give your SSID and password, but every time you edit and save the `CONFIG` file, the file is written again by the system itself to obfuscated your WiFi password and will place asterisk `*********` in the `APPNETWORKKEY` .

So if you edit something else then the WiFi-password, **it will use the actual `*********` as the password** when trying to make an connection.

So the working scenario here is to make a copy of your config file outside the Flashair (e.g. your Desktop) and edit the file there (so you don't have to repeat your password every time you change something), and after editing, just copy the file to your Flashair.

I find this one a big flaw in the setup, although I do understand passwords need to be obfuscated.

I also noticed that WiFi clients like Flashair with an incorrect password are shown in the client list of my WiFi router (Unify), they even got an IP-address (I had given the Flashair a static IP address), but you can't `ping` it, nor access the webinterface, or see it with a network scanner like iNet. That was something that got me stumbled for a while (I though WiFi clients only show up in your WiFi router when the password was right).

Answer (score 0):

After half a day of dabbling with the card. I found out that the mode for internet pass through is 4 instead of 5 as stated in the documentation. Additionally, the config file requires your internet's SSID and password.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that mode nr 4 is for Station Mode? I am using mode nr 5 which gives me opportunity to connect my WLAN.
One thing that you need remember is that FlashAir support only from **1 to 11 WiFi Channels.**

Comment: I couldn't get it connected in mode nr 5. I did the configuration on the GUI interface and it updated my configuration file to nr 4 even after I saved it on 5. Only when it was nr 4 did I manage to connect.